# client send sql request to node server

Tags: jquery, mysql, node.js, express, ejs

I'm trying to send a sql query in the form of a json from the javascript client side to the node-server and get back in return the result of the query but it looks like I can't get it right so that it works like intended.

I'm building the sql query when it need to be use, no input from the user at all. I'm building dynamique charts with some datas comming from a database so I would like to use the same json file, juste changing it in function of the chart that is loaded at the moment...
I don't know if I'm clear enough...

I'm using Express, mysql, ejs for engine views and Highcharts to create the different charts.

Here is the code server side:
- app.js:

```
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/dbIndex', dbIndex)
```

- dbIndex.js

```js
import express from "express";
import db from "../public/javascripts/db";
import Request from '../public/javascripts/request';

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next){
    var sql_request = req.query.sql;
    res.json({'status': 200, 'msg': 'success'})
    router.get("/Nb_plis_heure", (req, res, next) => {

        db.query(Request.getProductSQL(sql_request), (err, row)=> {
            if(!err) {
                res.send(row);
            }
        });    
    });
});

router.get("/Nb_plis_init", (req, res, next) => {

    db.query(Request.get10ProductSQL(), (err, row)=> {
        if(!err) {
            res.send(row);
        }
    });    
});

router.get("/Nb_plis_heure", (req, res, next) => {

    db.query(Request.getProductSQL(), (err, row)=> {
        if(!err) {
            res.send(row);
        }
    });    
});

module.exports = router;
```

And the little bit from the client side:

```
var sql = {
    sql: 'SELECT Nb_plis_heure,Nb_stack_jour FROM Production ORDER BY day DESC LIMIT 1'
}
$(function(){
    $.get('/dbIndex', sql, function(data){
        alert(data);
    })
})
```

Comment: Sending unfiltered sql from the client?  Sounds like a recipe for disaster.   Obligatory: https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: You would want to be _very_ careful executing SQL code from a client. You must remember you cannot trust what they send!

Comment: I'm not very fearfull of what the users will do, the server can only do "SELECT" query and none of them know what sql is... But I'm open to suggestions to do it more safely.

Comment: "I'm not very fearfull of what the users will do"... "none of them know SQL". Ok 1) your expected users are not the only people who can make HTTP requests to your server. Bots, viruses, script injection attacks, malicious users, hackers etc. Even if you're firewalled, password protected, virus-scanned etc, there's always a way in somewhere (usually via your unwitting users, ironically). 2) You can't be sure your users will always be unfamiliar with SQL. Summary: Your server should never trust **anything** sent to it, always validate everything. You never know who **really** sent it.

Comment: P.S. 3) "the server can only do "SELECT" ...that still has the potential for someone (or something) to view, and then steal, data that they shouldn't have access to. All queries are a risk. Maybe not a risk of data corruption, but potentially a risk of data leakage. Plus you have to make absolutely certain your webserver's permissions never get changed by accident so it can carry out other types of query. Better to close off the risk by whitelisting and santising everything the client sends.

Comment: Even better, don't make the client send SQL. Make it send items of data (e.g. lists of fields, and/or search criteria) which the server then validates, and uses to build the SQL itself. That way the client does not have direct control of what query is executed, and the server can check the incoming data item by item. As long as you do that correctly using parameterisation, with suitable escaping and whitelisting of bits that can't be parameterised, then that's far less likely to leave security holes.